# How to Php Array and render in smarty for Javascript?

Tags: php, json, smarty

I am using php as backend, and passing assosiative array to template. My template is using smarty 2.6.18.

php:
`$a = array("abc"=>"abc");`

template:
`var check = $a|@json_enode;`

This `var check` is returning `"{}";`

Not able to understand the behaviour of json_encode in smarty. While it is working with greater versions of smarty. I think there might be another way of doing in this version. Can anyone help here ?

Comment: You mean `json_encode` <-- typo here on your example.